# Compile quazip under windows 8.1 and qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, quazip

I'm new and trying to use Quazip under qt 5.5. So I just downloaded project sources from http://quazip.sourceforge.net/ and opened .pro file. When I try to build project I 've got multiple errors:

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory
```

To avoid building zlib on windows I just installed (from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm) complete pack for windows in C:\GnuWin32. Then I added this line in .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\GnuWin32\include
```

This generated another error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
```

But changing this line

```
#if 1           /* HAVE_UNISTD_H -- this line is updated by ./configure */
```

into this fixed the problem.

```
#if HAVE_UNISTD_H
```

Unfortunately now I get 25 unresolved external symbols, some of them:

```
quaadler32.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol adler32 referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned int __cdecl QuaAdler32::calculate(class QByteArray const &)" (?calculate@QuaAdler32@@UEAAIAEBVQByteArray@@@Z)
quacrc32.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol crc32 referenced in function "public: virtual unsigned int __cdecl QuaCrc32::calculate(class QByteArray const &)" (?calculate@QuaCrc32@@UEAAIAEBVQByteArray@@@Z)
unzip.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol crc32
quagzipfile.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gzopen referenced in function "private: void * __cdecl QuaGzipFilePrivate::open(class QString const &,char const *)" (?open@QuaGzipFilePrivate@@AEAAPEAXAEBVQString@@PEBD@Z)
quaziodevice.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol deflateInit_ referenced in function "public: virtual bool __cdecl QuaZIODevice::open(class QFlags<enum QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>)" (?open@QuaZIODevice@@UEAA_NV?$QFlags@W4OpenModeFlag@QIODevice@@@@@Z)
quaziodevice.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inflate referenced in function "protected: virtual __int64 __cdecl QuaZIODevice::readData(char *,__int64)" (?readData@QuaZIODevice@@MEAA_JPEAD_J@Z)
```

I tries adding this line:

```
LIBS += -LC:\GnuWin32\lib
```

But that didn't solve the problem. WHat is the easiest way to use Quazip under Qt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Download quazip source from [quzip site](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/)
2. Open by Qt Creator quazip.pri
3. Replace all strings #include "zlib.h" or "#include < zlib.h>"

to

```
#include <QtZlib/zlib.h>
```

4. Build project and run unit tests.

Comment: It works, thank you! But how am I supposed to know that qt has it owns implementation of zlib?

Comment: @Isaac Qt don't have own implementation of zlib. In $$[QTDIR]\Src\qtbase\src\3rdparty\zlib located zlib version, that Qt use. #include <QtLib/zlib.h> work just such as alias to zlib.h.

Comment: Fantastic, fixed that for me.  Other unresolved symbols, but this was great.  Thanks @Milovidov.

Comment: I think it was a compiler mismatch between my windows path an qtcreator. Working now by compiling everything from command line.